# Is GeForce GTX 1050 Cuda-Enabled?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I want to buy a laptop with graphic GeForce GTX 1050. In [nvidia site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#collapse4) 1050 desktop version is cuda-enabled, but it's not in notebook section.

Does that mean it's not cuda-enabled?
anyone has this graphic card and can check it.

(laptop is MSI)

Comment: I'd trust NVIDIA information since it is their technology - and especially since they said (near the bottom of the page) `Do I have a CUDA-enabled GPU in my computer?
Answer: Check the list above to see if your GPU is on it.`. Is there any particular reason you wanted it to be CUDA capable? Do you have CUDA-accelerated applications that can take advantage of it? If purely for gaming, then not much difference.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to run some app that use gpu cuda interface. It is somehow starnge; all 9-class are cuda-enabled, and in class 10, only 1050 doesn't support cuda? (just for notebook)

Answer (score 2):

I finally checked a laptop with GTX-1050. and seems support cuda.

[cuda-z](http://cuda-z.sourceforge.net/) output:
[cuda-z for 1050](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbZp7.png)

[gpu-caps](http://ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/) output:
[gpu caps result for 1050](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SMQ8.png)